# Are the glitches from the original pokemon generation 1 in the 3ds versions?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I'm thinking about buying the generation 1 games on the 3ds, but if they patched the glitches from the original game I'm not going to.

To be more specific, I'm wondering if the experience overflow glitch and the mew glitch still work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the games work the exact same way, and so do the glitches.

Answer (score 0):

I think one item manipulation glitch is different. But ither than that, they're all there. I can personally confirm the Mew glitch works